# How to deep copy full object behind boost::shared_ptr<T> into shared_ptr pointing to new location?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

How to copy full object behind `boost::shared_ptr<T>`: are there memcopy options (just create memory clone), or we shall create copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You need a copy constructor or an `operator=` that will perform the deep copy.

`boost::shared_ptr` cannot know your object's structure to do this for you. Neither can a "memory clone" operation.

Of course, this is only for objects, that need an explicitly defined copy constructor / `operator=` and the "trivial" ones make a shallow copy.

Comment: why default will not be enough?

Comment: Because the default copy constructor and `operator=` do a shallow copy, not a deep copy (in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact type of the object, then you should use a copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

If the objects is an instance of a class in an inheritance hierarchy, and you do not know the exact type of the object, then you should use a virtual clone function.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a copy constructor and write something like:

```
ptr.reset(new T);
*ptr  = *(otherObject.ptr);
```

in order to deep copy the pointer.

Comment: Why write a copy constructor if you're then not going to use it? Alternatively, why not recommend _using_ the copy constructor that you suggest creating?

Comment: @CBBailey: *ptr will resolve to a reference to the inner object of the shared ptr, hence using the copy constructor.